# MS Access Filter Subform (DataSheet) with another Subform (List)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a Project to be done in MS Access 2016, and stubled across an Issue, that should be easy to resolve, however, I have no clue on how to do it.

The Database I am developing is based on a huge, unfiltered datasheet exported by another database. I have a main form `headview` in which I placed two subforms `listview` an `detailview`. The `listview`is sorted by a combobox.

Now to what "should" happen: If you click on an entry of said `listview`, the `detailview` shows additional information of the clicked entry.

Both subforms are based on the same datasheet. So I went ahead and tried to match them via primary key entries. However, that didnt work. The `detailview` subform is still empty. I also tried to write a vba macro for the `listview` with `listview.click()` that didnt work either.

Is there a way to connect those two subforms within a main form? If so, how do I do that?

I am greatfull for any response,

Have a nice day
-Ninsa

Comment: If it must not be solved with subforms, you could handle all in one form, by binding this to the mentioned datasource and setting the form to `SplitView` (this shows a datasheet and a detail view simultanously).

Comment: @UnhandledException That was my first Intention when creating the Database, however, the group of end-users disliked it, therefore I have to build it around subforms..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I got the reason for error 2455, it's a timing problem.

When the procedure `Form_Current` of the listview form is called the first time, the detail subform is not yet bound to the detail subform control, which causes the error.

## Possible solutions

### Option1: Ignore error 2455

Either add `On Error Resume Next` in the top of the `Form_Current` procedure or rewrite it to handle that specific error 2455:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    On Error GoTo Catch

    With Me.Parent.DetailSubformControl.Form
        .Filter = "[ID] = '" & Me.ID.Value & "'"
        .FilterOn = True
    End With

Finally:
    Exit Sub

Catch:
    If Err.Number = 2455 Then Resume Finally
    MsgBox Err.Number & "(" & Err.Description & ") occured.", vbExclamation, "Attention"
    Resume Finally
End Sub
```

### Option2: Control the source objects of the subform controls

Clear the `Source Object` property of the subform controls in the head form and set them explicit when loading the head form.

That prevents the unlucky timing at all.

So in the head forms load event procedure add this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.DetailSubformControl.SourceObject = "Table1Detail"
    Me.DatasheetSubformControl.SourceObject = "Table1Datasheet"
End Sub
```

### Option3: Use Link Master/Child Fields

You could use the properties `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields` of the detail subform control.

Therefor you have to create a textbox control named `ID` on the head form and for cosmetic aspects hide it by setting its property `Visible` to `False`.

This new control will be bound to the detail subform control:
Set the property `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields` of the detail subform control on the head form both to `ID`.

The `Form_Current` procedure of the listview form then only contains this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ' Set the value of the hidden control 'ID' on the head form,
    ' which is bound to the detail subform control, to the selected ID.
    Me.Parent.ID.Value = Me.ID.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Fine! Anyway I would suggest to use option 3. It’s clean and most importantly it’s flexible because the subforms don‘t know each other. ;-)

Comment: Hello @Unhandled Exception
I redid the Database from scratch, I had too many Issues with my current design. In that, I used your Option 3 and it worked like a Charm, many thanks for your help with my Project :)

Answer (score 1):

You should handle filtering of the *detailview* on the `Listview_Current` event. That event fires as soon as `Listview` changes records.

You can either set up an event handler for the `Listview_Current` event on the listview's form module, or use `WithEvents` in the parent form to listen to that specific event.

If you choose the latter, note that it's required that Listview has a form module, else the events won't fire.

Comment: The Listview contains more than one Entry when Filtered. Does the `Listview_Current()` fire when i select one of the entries in the `listview` is marked? I want the `detailview`to show information for the selected / marked entry of the `listview`

Comment: It fires when you change the currently selected item. If you've added something like checkboxes to select items to be able to select multiple items, I recommend listening to events there, but if you're just using record navigation to select items the `Current` event should do.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your ID field of the datasource is `ID` and the detail subform control is named `DetailSubformControl`, this example works.

Place this code to the `Form_Current` event of the listview subform (which is fired on every record you move to):

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ' Set a reference to the detail subform control
    With Me.Parent.DetailSubformControl
        ' Set the filter of its contained form to the current ID of the listview.
        ' The "'" are only necessary if it is a text and not a numeric field.
        .Form.Filter = "[ID] = '" & Me.ID.Value & "'"
        .Form.FilterOn = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That sounds plausible to me, could you elaborate `detailsubformcontrol` to me, as I work in a german UI, and cannot quite pinpoint what that is supposed to be :) 
However, many thanks for the fast respone :)

Comment: When you placed the subform control on the headform, it got a name (each control has a name). I named it `DetailSubformControl`. You would have to use the name of your subform control instead.

Comment: I tried that, however, it throws the Runtimeerror 2455 marking `.Form.Filter = "[ID] =" & Me.ID.Value`

Comment: I changed the backticks, because ID is a autoNumericvalue

Comment: Funny Enough, It does work though. I do not quite know why.

Comment: So you don't get error 2455 any more and it works well now?

Comment: No I do keep getting the error, but i close the window and can use the database just fine

Comment: I'm right now preparing a more detailled answer. Please give me some minutes. ;-)